# Neo4j cypher: internal result being used as ID in a nested query

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

I use Neo4j 1.9.2 and I need to optimize the following query:

`START n=node:edge_iter(id='5'), r=relationship(*)
MATCH (m)-[:NEXT]->(n)
WHERE ID(r) = m.id
RETURN r`

It is deadly slow because of `relationship(*)`.

So I've create this query which doesn't work:

`START n=node:edge_iter(id='5')
MATCH (m)-[:NEXT]->(n)
WITH m.id as id
START r=relationship(id)
RETURN r`

Error message:

> expected relationship id, or *
>
> "START r=relationship(id)"

I get another error when I use `r=relationship({id})` because `{id}` should be a parameter.

My question is simple: how can I use `m.id` to get the corresponding row without making a second query?

A bit of context: I try to model an edge stream in Neo4j, which is a set of consecutive edges ordered by time of appearance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you are trying to get all relationships of the type "NEXT" and with the identifier that is the same as the starting node, if that's true, try the following query,

```
START n=node:edge_iter(id='5') 
MATCH (m)-[r:NEXT]->(n)
Where ID(r) = ID(n)
Return r
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not a solution: the relationship referenced by `m.id` is not connected to the starting node, so I can't use any classic traversal here.

To give more context, the nodes referenced by the index `edge_iter` have the property `id`, which references a relationship somewhere else in the graph. Two nodes referenced by `edge_iter` may be linked by a NEXT relationship because I need an iterator.

All I need to know is if it is possible to use `m.id` as a parameter of a nested query, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Do you know the expected relationship type in advance, or it might be any type?

Comment: The start doesn't take a variable as an id value. it looks like you have to use match to specify the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

From the Neo4j crew:

> not yet, in 2.0 it should do a direct lookup from the: where id(r) = id